# Updating data through several layers of views with ViewModel

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have several nested child views. I'm trying to update the value of an object in the most nested child view, and have that change reflected all the way up. I'm not sure if I should be using @Binding here, or something completely different. And if I *should* use @Binding, I'm not really sure how to best use it. I've left comments in each code snippet with additional questions.

Working backwards, from the most nested child view, here I'm updating `stop.timeStart` on button press here. This is what I need to have reflected in all other parent views.

```
struct StopTimePickerView: View {
    @Binding var stop: TripStop
    @State var startTime: Date?
    @Binding var showingTimePicker: Bool
    
    var onTimePicked: (_ startDate: Date?) -> Void
    
    init(stop: Binding<TripStop>, onTimePicked: @escaping (Date?) -> Void, showingTimePicker: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._stop = stop
        self.onTimePicked = onTimesPicked
        self._showingTimePicker = showingTimePicker
        self._startTime = State(initialValue: self.stop.timeStart?.getDate())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                stop.timeStart = "1"
                self.onButtonTapped(startTime)
            }, label: {
                Text("Done")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure if using `@Binding` is the right thing to do here, and I'm struggling to piece it all together in parent views.

Here's the next parent view:

```
struct StopDetailsView: View {
    @Binding var stop: TripStop
    @State private var showingTimePicker: Bool = false
    
    init(stop: Binding<TripStop>) {
        self._stop = stop
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        showingTimePicker.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Show picker")
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingTimePicker) {
                        StopTimePickerView(stop: $stop, onTimePicked: updateTime, showingTimePicker: $showingTimePicker)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateTime(startTime: Date?) {
        
    }
```

Moving onto the next parent view...

```
struct StopView: View {
    @Binding var stop: TripStop
    
    init(stop: Binding<TripStop>) {
        self._stop = stop
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: StopDetailsView(stop: $stop)) {
            HStack {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                        .fill(Color("Primary Color").opacity(0.1))
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And again, moving onto the next parent view. This is where I get confused as to how to use `@Binding`. Should `days` be @Binding? How would it be used?

```
struct TripDayView: View {
    // Should this have a @Binding?
    var days: [Day]?
    
    var body: some View {
        // If days is @Binding, how does this look?
        if let days = self.days {
            ForEach(days, id: \.id) { day in
                VStack {
                    if let stops = day.stops {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(stops, id: \.id) { stop in
                                StopView(stop: stop)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what `Day` looks like:

```
struct Day: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var stops: [TripStop]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "date"
        case stops = "stops"
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is the top-level parent view:

```
struct TripPageView: View {
    // Should I use @Binding here?
    @Binding var trip: Trip    
    @StateObject private var vm = TripViewModel(tripService: TripService())
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    StopsView(vm: vm, trip: trip)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            // Fetches the days in the ViewModel
            vm.fetchTripDays(tripId: trip.id)
        }
    }
}

struct StopsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: TripViewModel
    
    var trip: Trip
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Is using $vm correct here?
            TripDayView(days: $vm.days)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `TripViewModel` class:

```
class TripViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let tripService: TripServiceProtocol
    @Published var days: [Day]?
    
    init(tripService: TripServiceProtocol) {
        self.tripService = tripService
    }

    func fetchTripDays(tripId: Int) {
        tripService.getTripDays(tripId: tripId)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { data in
                print("Received \(data)")
        }, receiveValue: {[weak self] data in
            self?.days = data.data.days
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
        print(cancellables)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Binding if the object is a value type use Bindable if the item is Observable and use ObservedObject if the item is an ObservableObject. You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Comment: Have a look at these  **official** links, they give you some good examples of how to manage data in your app, ios16:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)  or ios17 [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue you can declare a `@State` to hold the time at the highest common parent it is needed and pass bindings down.

Also I would recommend some improvements to the SwiftUI code. Remove view model objects - in SwiftUI the View structs are the view model. Remove all the Combine code because you are using async/await and it seems its trying to reimplement `View`'s `body` and sending a pipeline down a `sink` is almost always bad. Use `EnvironmentKey` for service structs, so they can be mocked when previewing. See Apple's [authorizationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/authorizationcontroller) for an example. Use `.task` correctly by assigning a result to a state, e.g. something like this:

```
@Environment(\.tripService) var tripService
@State var tripDays: [TripDays] = []
let trip: Trip
...
.task(id: trip.id) { // runs on appear and when id changes
    tripDays = await tripService.fetchTripDays(tripId: trip.id)
}
```